# How to pass array parameter from power shell to arm template

Tags: powershell, azure-rm-template

In below script, I want to pass an array parameter to a JSON file:

```
"topics": {
          "type": "array",
          "metadata": {
              "description": "List of topics"
           }
          }
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Script:

```
$version = "2"
$deploymentname = "fapp-dxb-$version" 
$rgname = "rg_fapp01"
$arrayParam = ???
New-AzResourceGroup -Name $rgname `
                    -Location 'West Europe' `
                    -Tag @{costcenter="01"; service="NOTASSIGNED"} `
                    -Force

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name $deploymentname `
                              -eventGridDomainName 'egdfap01' `
                              -storageAccountName 'snowflake' `
                              -deadletterBlobName 'dletterblob' `
                              -location 'West Europe' `
                              -topics $arrayParam `
                              -ResourceGroupName $rgname `
                              -TemplateFile  'azuredeploy.json'
```

Comment: Show example of your array, few elements...

Comment: It's not really clear how that JSON relates to the Powershell code below. Could you clarify what you want to do with the JSON? I assume you want some if it in the `$arrayParam` variable.

Comment: What do you want to pass in $arrayParam array, you can simply put that array. in variable. Please provide the template so we can have a look at it.